# JSESSIONID with Node.js

Tags: node.js, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

A node.js/express.js app is trying to communicate with a Spring Boot backend service that uses Spring Security.  However, the `JSESSIONID` and `csrf token` from the backend Spring Boot app do not seem to be sent to the node.js app.  This causes problems maintaining state.

**How can I maintain state between node.js and Spring Boot apps that need to talk with each other?**

The Spring Boot app being used for testing has already been written by Spring, so the solution needs to involve getting node.js/Express.js to hear any state information being sent from the Spring App.

I tried using the Express.js `req` api to print out headers, params, cookies, etc, but was not able to find `JSESSIONID`, `csrf`, or other cookies or headers.

However, when Spring Boot apps talk to each other, this information is shared.